# Sequilize association for 2 foriegn key of same model

Tags: mysql, orm

I need to execute below query using sequelize

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  haulerrfquotes
    LEFT JOIN  quotes
      ON   quotes.jobId = haulerrfquotes.jobId
      AND  haulerrfquotes.haulerId = quotes.haulerId
    WHERE  haulerrfquotes.jobId = '11'
```

But i am not getting how to use two foriegn keys in same model(haulerrfquotes) and to create association of both foriegn keys to single model (quotes) in node.js ORM sequelize.js

Answer (score 0):

`haulerrfquotes` needs `INDEX(jobId)`.

`quotes` needs `INDEX(haulerId, jobId)` (or in the opposite order).

Are node.js and/or sequelize.js not providing that?  If not, abandon them.